# How to route google app engine cron job to a module and version

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron

I have a Google app engine cron job that I want to test out and run on a specific module and version. How do I do this?

I have tried specifying the target in cron.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
  <cron>
    <url>/purgeAll</url>
    <description>delete old entities</description>
    <schedule>every day 10:45</schedule>
    <timezone>America/Los_Angeles</timezone>
    <target>ninaddev</target>
  </cron>
</cronentries>
```

I also tried adding a dipatch.xml file in the default package:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dispatch-entries>
  <dispatch>
    <module>internal</module>
    <url>*/purgeAll</url>
  </dispatch>
</dispatch-entries>
```

The result is that the cron runs on the specified version (ninaddev) but not the specified module (internal), and I can see it running here with the logs.

I think this is because the dispatch file can't target versions other than the default version https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/routing: "You can create a dispatch file to override the default routing for URLs that do not specify a version (described above)."

One last thing that might be relevant is that I am uploading my modules (default and internal) together in an EAR structure as specified here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/

Any help on how to get the cron running on the "ninaddev" version and the "internal" module would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to route cron jobs to specific module versions, but I have tried them in Python.

This how I did it:

1. I used the target field only for the version, internal in your case.
2. In dispatch I routed everything for a certain URL path to the module (*/ninaddev-url in your case).

In YAML notation (you may use them also with your Java project):

cron.yaml

```
cron:
- description: new job
  url: /ninaddev-url
  target: internal
```

dispatch.yaml

```
dispatch:
- url: '*/ninaddev-url'
  module: ninaddev
```

You can secure the access to those URLs if needed.

Comment: uow, neat trick! Half of the info in each file and it unbelievably works.